# Does pthread_mutex_init always return 0?

Tags: linux, pthreads, mutex

I'm looking at the `pthread_mutex_init` man-page on two PCs.
One says:

> If successful, the pthread_mutex_destroy() and pthread_mutex_init() functions shall return zero; an error number shall be returned to indicate the error.

The other says:

> pthread_mutex_init always returns 0.

Which is true?

Comment: where did you see the "other"?

Comment: @tigercosmos - I'm not sure how to "identify" the other PC -- what information do you need? `uname -a` gives `Linux linuxbox 5.4.0-42-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 10 00:24:02 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: @tigercosmos - and `lsb_release -a` gives `Distributor ID: Ubuntu`, `Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS`, `Release:        20.04`, `Codename:       focal`

Answer (score 5):

The POSIX thread API, a.k.a. "pthreads" is standardized as part of (naturally) POSIX.  [Its current specifications for `pthread_mutex_init()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutex_init.html) say, in part:

> If successful, the `pthread_mutex_destroy()` and `pthread_mutex_init()`
> functions shall return zero; otherwise, an error number shall be
> returned to indicate the error.

That is identical to the first claim you quoted.  The specifications go on to describe several specific cases where `pthread_mutex_init()` is *required* to fail, and one where it is *allowed* to fail.  As far as POSIX is concerned, then, `pthread_mutex_init()` can indeed fail, returning an error number.  The details have changed only slightly since the initial version of these specifications were published -- no published version of POSIX says that `pthread_mutex_init()` always returns 0.

But POSIX is specifying an API, not documenting a concrete implementation of that API. There are several implementations of pthreads, each with many versions.  It is possible that in some of those, none of the conditions in which `pthread_mutex_init()` may or must fail can in fact arise, and the documentation of such an implementation would not be incorrect to claim, as your second quotation does, that `pthread_mutex_init()` always returns 0 (because it never fails).

Thus, the two claims are not mutually exclusive, but they are not necessarily talking about the quite the same thing.  POSIX documents the behavior that can be expected and must be accommodated within the universe of all conforming implementations, whereas the latter claim must be interpreted as documenting the behavior of one specific implementation.

You would be wise to program for the more general of the two (that `pthread_mutex_init()` can fail, returning an error code), as that is more portable.

Comment: Any idea why the man page on the other PC describes the narrower/specific implementation rather than the POSIX description?
The second PC is a new laptop that I'm setting up anew.I originally noticed that "`man pthread_mutex<tab>`" did not auto-complete...some googling led me to try `sudo apt install glibc-doc-reference`.
This seemed to add man-pages for the `pthread_mutex*` functions - but apparently implementation-specific, not POSIX.
Maybe this is a separate question, but what should I do to install POSIX man pages?

Comment: @StoneThrow, you are evidently reading the man page provided by glibc.  I cannot speak to why that project's maintainers chose to write implementation-specific documentation for a function defined by a standard API, instead of, say, adding implementation notes.  I observe, however, that on my CentOS system, `man pthread_mutex_init` gets me a page from chapter 3p (i.e. the POSIX manual), which describes the POSIX semantics.  In that distribution, the page belongs to the "man-pages" package, which seems to be based on docs from the Linux Documentation Project.

Comment: A little more research led me to find that I apparently need to manually install the POSIX man pages. On my Ubuntu PC, I did this with `sudo apt install manpages-posix` and `sudo apt install manpages-posix-dev`. After doing so, I now have a man 3p entry for `posix_mutex_init` (which actually redirects me to `posix_mutex_destroy`), which gives me the expected description "`If successful, the pthread_mutex_destroy() and pthread_mutex_init() functions shall return zero; otherwise, an error number shall be returned to indicate the error.`"